# Can I use F#'s Ticked Function name notation for C# Methods?

Tags: c#, f#

In the F# language it is possible to name functions using ``` ``Ticked function name notation`` ```. It is extremely convenient for unit tests naming.

Is there any possibility to do this in the C# language? We can always use `Underscored_method_names` or `PascalMethodNames`, but it isn't as easy to read.

Comment: I don't think that the question on the link really answers my question. Yes, we can somehow answer my question using facts described in the question on the link, but still it doesn't provide a single straightforward answer.

Comment: You're right. I didn't read your question closely enough, sorry!

Comment: The problem is you're equating test names to method names. Instead, use a simple string to represent test names.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, basically. C# type and member names cannot include whitespace (and cannot start with a number). There is support for disambiguating names from reserved keywords (the `@` prefix), but that is about it.

When the long name is *for display*, often `DisplayNameAttribute` is useful, i.e.

```
[DisplayName("My class")]
public class MyClass {
    [DisplayName("Full name")]
    public string FullName {get;set;}
}
```

- but this won't help with your unit test desires.

Answer (score 5):

Putting actual spaces (ASCII 32) in identifier names is not possible.

**However**, see [this blog](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/02/17/spaces-in-identifier-names-in-c/) about (ab)using Unicode to insert other code points that look like spaces. The author describes a way to somewhat automate this using hotkeys.

**I do not recommend you do this** as it will cause serious problems with maintainability and debugging.

Comment: that's all kinds of evil; I like

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not a feature of the language.  There is no method for escaping a method name such that you can use spaces within it.

Answer (score 1):

What many folks don't realize is that you are not limited to English when naming C# identifiers, classes, members, etc. Yes, you can write your app in Russian or any other language:

```
var форма = new HtmlForm();

int ワン = 1;
```

Maybe, you can utilize something like that for your purposes instead?

Comment: Yeah, we can combine this approach with the dvnrrs's answer, but it still lacks convenience, it would not be too easy to maintain.